# MVC Model Binding failing when sorting viewmodel elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a working scenario - 
My viewmodel contains a list of Employee objects.

```
List<Employee> Employees;
```

I populate this list by the following:

```
Employees = EmployeeService.GetAll().ToList();
```

This works fine. I can view the employees, update their data, post back and save to db.

However, when I try and sort the list of Employees in the viewmodel before sending to the view by replacing the code above with:

```
Employees = EmployeeService.GetAll().OrderBy(e=>e.Name).ToList();
```

The view is populated nicely with the ordered employee details. Unfortunately when I post back this viewmodel to the controller, the viewmodel.Employees is null / empty.

I'd appreciate any help if anyone has any ideas what I might be doing wrong here or why this is happening only when I sort.

Regards

Edit--

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    EmployeesViewModel _viewModel = new EmployeesViewModel();
    return View(_viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(EmployeesViewModel viewModel)
{
    // HERE ** - viewModel.Employees is NULL
    EmployeesService.UpdateAllEmployees(viewModel);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Edit- Sample Markup --

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Employees.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(e => e.Employees[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(e => e.Employees[i].Name)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style = "width: 125px">
                @Model.Employees[i].Name
            </td>
            <td style = "width: 125px">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(e => e.Employees[i].IsActive)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Edit - Class Details

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string InitialCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {

    }

}


public class EmployeesViewModel
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    private readonly EmployeesService EmployeesService;

    public EmployeesViewModel()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
        EmployeesService = new EmployeesService();
        // Employees = EmployeesService.GetAll().ToList(); //THIS WORKS
        Employees = EmployeesService.GetAll().OrderBy(e=>e.Name).ToList();
    }
}
```

EmployeesService simply calls the DB Context and returns all records.

Comment: There's nothing really major there as far as I can see.
See above.

Comment: Can you show your View markup? Is ModelState empty in your POST action?

Comment: In your controller code there is no line with list of employees loading. Where is this action happening? Can post code that does this?

Comment: This employees loading is happening in the viewmodel constructor. Code posted above (the second line of code at the start of the post which works and the modified third line which does not work)

Comment: As far as I know model binder cannot bind the list (not sure about MVC3) it can only bind properties if the names are matching. Are you sure the Model is populated correctly in un-ordered Post method?

Comment: Viewmodel constructor populates the Employees list. When I don't add the OrderBy(e=>e.name).ToList() it works perfectly. Updates / Saves to the DB and all.

Comment: One more idea of mine requires some more details about your code. Tell us about `Employee` class, however little relevant it might seem. How can it be instantiated, does it have a parameterless constructor? Actually the same questions go to `EmployeesViewModel`.

Comment: Both Employee and EmployeesViewModel have paramaterless constructors. There is nothing unusual about either. I'll post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML form elements need to be rendered in a way that the DefaultModelBinder can correctly parse out the collection. Check out this: https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem .

Also read [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) and [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).

Comment: Okay, I have read something in one of your links - "Note that the index must be an unbroken sequence of integers starting at 0 and increasing by 1 for each element."

When I sort the list, this rule is broken.

Comment: You could also index them using a GUID instead of an integer. That is what the BeginCollectionItem helper does. When using GUID's, the order of the items does not matter.

Comment: You're correct (and were right to stand by your answer... :) ), I was using the Employee.Id here. As a result, when they were sorted the sequence was changed. Thankyou for pointing me in the right direction.